# Is it time for a [windows-8] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

People are starting to ask Windows 8 questions. In fact, I've found some going back to November of last year. It would be helpful if these were tagged, but I don't want to mass-bump them, especially the "oh noes I am sure X is not supported and it's not fair and what am I going to do" ones that don't have a real answer. On the other hand, speculation and semi-answers to those are more available now than they were 7 months ago.

So, should I start tagging questions I see that deserve the tag? Should I restrict myself to just those that are pretty recent - let's say Wednesday's first public demo of the Windows 8 UI as a line in the sand - or do any I come across?

Comment: If the question is genuinely specific to Windows-8, then it might deserve the tag.  Such occurrences should be somewhat rare, unless someone is asking specific questions about new Windows-8 features on SuperUser.

Comment: On SO people are asking "will my VB6 apps still work on Windows 8?" "Will <specific dll> still be on Windows 8 and if not what will I do instead?" and other programming questions. Answers beyond guesswork are currently impossible.

Comment: The tag is fine for those questions, even though the questions themselves are not that good.

Comment: There is a single video out as far as I've found. Tag-worthy?

Comment: @six - there are at least two videos, some speculations based on job listings, and a few teaser blogs. This makes the questions hard to answer. They are, nonetheless, being asked.

Answer (score 9):

Because not even Microsoft has said anything definitive about the technical specifications and capabilities of Windows 8, it is not fair for us to make objective and definitive answers on questions. All answers at this point will be subjective.

Therefore, this means that all the questions are, as of this point in time, purely speculative and subjective.

They may be valid questions, but it's too soon to answer them *for sure*.

I say close as S&A.

> It's impossible to objectively answer this question;

Comment: On further retrospection, I don't think that I really answered the question, since that was about tags, and I said about posts. But never the less, I stand by my suggestion, and apparently the community does as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to create the tag now, so that speculation and the like can be tagged with it. For now, it can be used as a honeypot by folks who feel it's too soon to answer questions on the topic. As real info comes out, questions in this tag can survive.

I tagged the really old questions now just so they won't get retagged (and bumped) later when there are high quality questions on Windows 8 that can actually be answered. If I come across other Windows 8 questions I'll tag them.

Also, I asked this about SO but I see that Programmers also is gathering Windows 8 questions, and they are closing fast. Just a data point.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing for me is that Windows-8 is still a code name.  If we use a windows-8 tag now, when the final name is announced every question bearing that should be updated to use a tag with the final name instead.  The tag synonym feature likely makes much easier than it was previously, so it's not that important from a technical standpoint.  I just bring this up because it makes sense to me as a litmus test: if we don't even have a real name for the project, how can we tag it correctly?

Comment: Because you have to assign a name to a thing before you can refer to it? I don't feel like that's a reason to ignore it, since the devs can fix that later.

Comment: Right - we had [tag:C++0x] for years and are just talking about switching to [tag:c++11] now. That's not an issue for me. We will still be calling it Windows 8 in September when the floodgates open for dev questions and the tag will most definitely be needed then.